# Load balance solr search

Tags: solr, cassandra, solrj

I am trying to implement search in datastax cassandra using solr. I have two nodes running both cassandra and solr. I am able to perform solr search using solrj. However I have hardcoded solr url of one of the node. I would like to know what configuration/code change I need to change so that solr nodes can be chosen directly.

At this stage, I am reading solrUrl from an external file and passing it as an argument to HttpSolrServer.

```
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(solrUrl);
```

External file contains solrUrl

```
Solr.URL=http://192.168.100.12:8983/solr/
```

Also what improvements I can do to existing approach?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the [LBHttpSolrServer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/LBHttpSolrServer.html) (remember: only use it for querying), which allows you to provide several servers that SolrJ will use to distribute its queries.
- If you have Solr Cloud cluster, you can use the ZooKeeper-aware server in SolrJ to get your queries automagically distributed.
- Third, you can set up a regular HTTP load balancer (such as haproxy, varnish, etc.) to distribute the requests for you and handle new servers coming online and servers disappearing.
- You could also read a random line in the file instead of one specific server, or use a separator for the configuration line and split on that separator and pick a server on random. It won't allow you to dynamically adjust the weights depending on query times (which a HTTP Load Balancer could do), but it would probably work Good Enough.

Comment: thank you very much for reply. However if I use option of going with LBHttpSolrServer, how will this work if I add two more solr nodes but replication set between only 2 nodes? Will that affect the performance?

Comment: @user1247412 If you don't have the same dataset on each node, you're talking sharding which is a different concept. You won't be able to load balance a single request to either of the shards in that case, you'll have to collect the results from both (using the shards parameter). But you might want to switch to SolrCloud if you're starting to both replicate and shard, as this is what SolrCloud does automagically for you.

Comment: Does Zookeeper work for DSE solr search also? Because I thought not relying on zookeeper is one of the advantage of DSE Solr.

Comment: @user1247412 DSE Search does not use ZooKeeper, as it relies on a combination of Cassandra's distribution mechanisms and proprietary distributed search logic.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe thank you for the information. How can I initialize my HttpSolrServer. Should I use load balanced IP to initialize HttpSolrServer or use LBHttpSolrServer and pass all the solr IPs or I can use any one of solr IP to initialize HttpSolrServer?